# How to replace regular expression?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I do replacing

```sql
SET @data = REPLACE(@data, 'Riched20 10.0.19041}', '');
```

It is ok, but recently I have detected that it can be

```
Riched20 10.0.18362 etc
```

How can I  replace in common case like `'Riched20 ...}'`?

Can I use a regular-expression?

It should be implementation in T-SQL

Comment: SQL Server have native support for pattern replacement. If you want to use Regex, you'll need to "invest" in CLR objects.

Comment: It is good idea but the matter is SQL Server does not support SQL CLR in AWS and in Azure.

Comment: "In Azure" is vague; certainly an Azure SQL Managed Instance can use CLR. Microsoft even have a [video](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/data-exposed/its-just-sql-clr-in-azure-sql-database-managed-instance) on it.

Comment: Also, if you are using a cloud-hosted version, you should really be noting that in your tags.

Comment: Add appropriate tags to your question to indicate your SQL Server platform.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have added: SQL Server 2019. It can be in AWS, Azure but I need to implement it in pure T-SQL

Comment: How *complex* is this going to get? Could you have *mutiple* instances of `'Riched20%}'` in a single value?

Comment: @Larnu No, it is beginning of RTF file,  its header, it can be once only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* the problem is as simple as this question makes it out to be then you could, instead, find the position of the string `'Riched20'` in your value, and then the position of the first `}` that appears after it and use `STUFF` to remove the text in that range.

This *assumes* that the value will *always* have a `}` after `'Riched20'`, and that if there is a `}` then `'Riched20'` also appears. If this isn't the case you will get the value `NULL`.

```sql
DECLARE @data varchar(100) = 'sdjkafhbgtajl asdgasdf, Riched20 10.0.19041} dlkghbsdfl';

SET @data = STUFF(@data, CHARINDEX('Riched20',@data),CHARINDEX('}',@data,CHARINDEX('Riched20',@data)) - CHARINDEX('Riched20',@data) +1,'');

SELECT @data;
```

If you need "true" pattern replacement, then you are out of luck; T-SQL does not support this as the comments mention.

Comment: Ok, by the way it can be the solution. I will try this approach